# Referenced file contains errors spring-beans-4.0.xsd

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

i really don't check what is here the problem.
Can somebody help me?

Cheers,
Markus

[Link to Image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts83u.png)

Comment: Don't link images to text. Include the problematic code in your question, any errors you're getting, what you've tried, and the problem you're trying to solve. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.8.xsd

***Try to add this schema location***